# Automatic tagging of the questions

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Most of the times we see that there are no relevant tags for the question.

How about automating this task and also allowing the user to edit them?

Comment: How would you suggest that automatic tagging be accomplished?

Comment: Once they enter the Title & description for the question, we can process the content and come up with relevant tags..

Comment: Most of the time I see relevant tags, and also relevant question on my favorite tags. If I see question with incorrect tags I will edit it with the correct tags

Comment: @Oded: May not be correct, users can still edit it, and OP too.

Comment: perhaps you could explain "process the content" in much much more detail?

Comment: @RobertLongson: like detecting programming language, or looking for the similar questions asked, the user's history of questions asked and so many factors may come into picture.. How to do is a different question?
What I am asking, is it a good feature worth discussing "How to achieve it". I have no experience in machine learning to give more accurate answer.

Comment: Guys, please give me a call when you're done implementing this, I'd like to build on it to add automatic answering. Should be easy.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: Nice sarcasm. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The system already does this:

[image: Suggested tags when creating a new question]

If the system doesn't suggest any tags for you, consider that the question doesn't contain enough relevant content for it to do anything with. It's a helper at best; it cannot replace conscious effort by a human, and it's certainly not magic.

Comment: Honestly, given the bad tags and titles endemic everywhere, I don't think even **conscious effort by a human** can replace conscious effort by a human.

Comment: @Nathan, wait, how many humans are there on each side again? I'm confused.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: Depends on what you mean by *side*, fragile meatbag. :P

Comment: @Nathan, so you're Aaron Stack. I should have known :]